# How to pack application using Jelastic App Packaging?

Tags: jelastic

Jelastic docs http://docs.jelastic.com/app-packaging says that it is possible to pack application to make it much easier to install for the end-user.

But no information how to pack application and create such button.

Any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mostly relates to Hosting Providers, they can pack any available app and then get it published for end-users. But you as end-user can easily contact your Hosting Provider support services and discuss application you want to be available via "One CLick Button intsallation".